# What is Entity Framework Include() and when to use it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a look at definitions and examples of EF `Include()` method but unfortunately, there is not a proper explanations for my question "What is Entity Framework Include() and when to use it?".

Here is an example usage. What is the general purpose of it and why / when should I use it?

```
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
        var list = context.Customers
            .Include(c => c.Invoices)    
            .ToList();    
        
        foreach (var customer in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Customer Name: {0}", customer.Name);
            foreach (var customerInvoice in customer.Invoices)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tInvoice Date: {0}", customerInvoice.Date);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Include has been used when navigation properties need to be associated with lookups.

Comment: It is basically a JOIN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case I assume "Customers" and "Invoices" are two separate tables.

Let's say you got one customer :

```
var customer = context.Customers.FirstOrDefault();
```

If you try to reach the invoices for that customer :

```
customer.Invoices
```

What will happens? It will depends your ORM configuration. There are 2 modes.

**Lazy loading**
With that mode, which is the default one I think, you will have a first call to the database to retrieve the customer (but only the customer) then a second call to the database to retrieve the invoices for that customer. But that second call will only happens when you will try to reach the invoices.

**Eager loading**
If you don't want to have multiple database calls and you want to get all data in one call you can disable the lazy loading. But if you get the customer the same way I showed above you will not get the invoices (you will get "null" instead).
The "Include" allow EF to know you want to retrieve the customer AND the invoices in one database call:

```
var customer = context.Customers.Includes(c => c.Invoices).FirstOrDefault();
```

And when you will try to get the invoices for that customer, everything will be already in memory so no additional database call.

Comment: Very good explanations, thanks a lot. Voted up and marked as answer of course.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Invoice id is primary key and customers.invoiceid is foreign key.
If you map the proper navigation properties

The final statement which calls Include("Invoices") may look like this:

SELECT *
FROM Customers JOIN Invoices ON Customers.InvoiceId = Invoices.Id;